# Loop through table, shading empty rows and deleting spaces in occupied cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to loop through the third column of each row of a table.
If that cell is blank, it should shade the entire row 
If that cell is occupied, it should look for any spaces and replace all spaces with a single `#` (for example `123    abc` becomes `123#abc`).
It should not run on the header row of the table.

Some random items-
the worksheet name is `Quote`
table name is `QuoteTable`
shading should be RGB(255, 248, 220)
The number of rows in the table will always vary, but the macro will always be checking the contents of the third column of the table which is named `Model #`.

Thanks for the responses, I will try each one, and in the meantime I came up with this--- which does everything except it highlights every single row from A-N not just the correct ones.

```
Public Sub ValidateSKUs()
Dim sMfrPN As String
Dim tbl1 As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set tbl1 = Sheets("Quote").Range("QuoteTable")
    For Each myCell In tbl1.Columns(3).Cells
    If myCell.Value = "" Then
            Sheets("Quote").Range("A" & myCell & ":N" & myCell).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 248, 220)
            Sheets("Quote").Range("A" & myCell & ":N" & myCell).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    Else
        sMfrPN = CleanUpPN(myCell)
            myCell = sMfrPN
    End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Function CleanUpPN(ByVal sMfrPN As String) As String
Dim sPN As String
'Trim trailing spaces
sPN = Trim(sMfrPN)
'Replace space with #
sPN = Replace(sPN, " ", "#")
'remove multiple # (e.g. ##)
Do Until InStr(1, sPN, "##") = 0
    sPN = Replace(sPN, "##", "#")
Loop
CleanUpPN = sPN
End Function
```

Comment: " loop through the third column of each row ", would that be the same as looping through Column "C"?

Comment: yes, looping through column c of "QuoteTable"
I'm not sure if it's best to refer to it as "C" or "Model #"
I had a macro that worked fine when it was in a range, but would shade empty rows after the last used row, so I decided to use a table instead of a range, and now have to re-write the macro as it no longer works properly

Answer (score 2):

VBA coding for a structured table can be a pain. You can either deal with the table as a [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx) or `Set` a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) variable to the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214261%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and deal with the cell addresses as you would with any other worksheet reference.

```
Sub fix_model_no()
    Dim mn As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")    '<~~ set this properly!
        With .ListObjects("QuoteTable")
            For Each mn In Range("QuoteTable[Model '#]")
                If Len(Trim(mn.Value2)) Then
                    Intersect(.DataBodyRange, Rows(mn.Row)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                    mn = Replace(Application.Trim(mn.Value2), Chr(32), Chr(35))
                Else
                    mn.ClearContents
                    Intersect(.DataBodyRange, Rows(mn.Row)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3  'red
                End If
            Next mn
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The single tick in `QuoteTable[Model '#]` is necessary to reference the `Model #` column. Any reference to a ListObject table likes to know which worksheet the table resides on.

You may wish to consider Conditional Formatting for the row highlighting based upon the blank cells in column C.

[image: Table VBA Code ListObject]

Comment: like your use of Application.Trim but would it work if the value is "123     abc      " instead?

Comment: The VBA [Trim function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) removes leading/trailing spaces but the worksheet's [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) removes leading/trailing spaces as well as inline double spaces. Of course, you could just try it and report back.

Answer (score -1):

Change "Z" to whatever column you require

```
Sub Oh_Ya()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rws As Long, r

    Set sh = Sheets("Quote")
    With sh
        rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & rws)
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            c = Replace(c, " ", "#")
            If c = "" Then
                r = c.Row
                Range("A" & r & ":Z" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 248, 220)
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```